# How to replace Iceweasel with Firefox for headless Cucumber/Capybara tests?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara, headless

I am running a set of Cucumber/Capybara tests with Selenium, using the headless gem in a Debian VM. For  some reasons that I won't go into here, I would like to replace Iceweasel with a real Firefox installation.

So I uninstalled iceweasel, and the followed these instructions: http://www.fandigital.com/2012/09/install-real-firefox-in-debian.html

> **Download Firefox**
>
> Download latest version of the original Mozilla Firefox for Linux from the official Mozilla website here, and put it in the Downloads folder within your Home directory (/home/YourUserName/Downloads).
>
> **Install Firefox**
>
> Copy and extract Firefox archive Open Terminal, and change directory (cd) to the Downloads folder:
>
> `cd /Downloads`
>
> Then run the following commands (one-by-one):
>
> - `sudo cp firefox-*.tar.bz2 /opt`
> - `cd /opt`
> - `sudo tar -xvf firefox-*.tar.bz2`
> - `sudo rm firefox-*.tar.bz2`
>
> **Create symbolic link to firefox binary**
>
> Backup (move) any existing firefox bin:
>
> `sudo mv /usr/bin/firefox /usr/bin/firefox.backup`
>
> **Create symbolic link to the real firefox binary:**
>
> `sudo ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox`

As soon as I start my tests, I unfortunately run into the following error: `unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds`. I have not been able to solve this problem. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: What verison of firefox and selenium do you have?

Comment: Firefox 21.0 for Linux (just downloaded today), and selenium (0.2.9), selenium-client (1.2.18), selenium-webdriver (2.32.0). I also did a fresh install of another VM, and I think that one downloaded the newest versions of the above gems when installing them...

Comment: I have a working combination of FF17 and Selenium-webdriver 2.32.1. Also i hope you have XVFB installed? And started it successfully before running the tests?

Comment: @amey: I have XVFB installed - it is started by the [headless gem](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using PhantomJS and am very pleased with it. Much faster than the previous setup.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when the Selenium Server version that you have does not support the Firefox browser version. Try using a stable compatible combination of Firefox Browser and Selenium Server.

Comment: I have installed Firefox 19, but I still get the same error, unfortunately. As soon as I switch back to Iceweasel, I have no problems starting the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the latest selenium standalone server version and latest firefox version to avoid connection issues.